# Create and publish collection of public domain poems from 19th century

Tags: legal, poetry

Can I create a collection of original 19th century public domain poems without violating copyright laws?

Comment: What do you mean by 'create'? Please be specific.

Comment: If you know the poems are public domain, then what's the problem?

Comment: Why do you specify "19th century public domain poems"? "19th century" is quite irrelevant. It does not even imply that the work is public domain. For example, the 19th century paintings of Kandinsky will be promoted to public domain only in 2015.

Answer (score 5):

While technically you could claim a copyright on your collection, you would not have any claim of copyright for any of the individual poems included in that collection. The problem would be in getting any publisher to allow you to actually publish the collection.

All of the major e-book publishers have very strict guidelines regarding the republishing of public domain works. Amazon's Kindle guidelines in particular expressly forbid the publishing of any public domain works **as part of a collection**. They specifically require that you differentiate your work from the original in one of the following ways:

> • (Translated) - A unique translation
>
> • (Annotated) - Contains annotations (unique, hand-crafted additional
>   content including study guides, literary critiques, detailed
>   biographies, or detailed historical context)
>
> • (Illustrated) - Includes 10 or more unique illustrations relevant to
>   the book
>
> Books that meet this criteria must include (Translated), (Annotated),
>   or (Illustrated) in the title field.

[KDP - Publishing Public Domain Content](https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A2OHLJURFVK57Q)

It is important to note that this criteria pertains specifically to the republishing of a complete public domain work. If you are trying to publish a collection of works, for example poetry, then their guidelines will not permit you to do so. This is especially true if these poems are freely available on the Internet.

Also, you will want to make absolutely certain that the poems you want to include truly are in the public domain. It is rare that individual poems are registered for a copyright because it is easier for a publisher to copyright a collection or an anthology. If any of the poems you want to use in your collection were copyrighted as part of another collection or an anthology, then that copyright may have been passed along to heirs or other parties.

On top of that, it is not uncommon for poetry to be published in multiple forms. For example, a poem may have been published in two different collections, but the author may have chosen to retain the copyright on only one of those collections. Another possibility is that the rights to a poem were sold to a publisher to be included in an anthology. In this example, the original author might have granted ownership of the copyright to the publisher.

It's a lot easier to ascertain that a full novel is in the public domain because it is essentially a single title. However, with something like poetry or short stories that tend to appear in many types of publications, it is harder to verify that each individual title is truly in the public domain.

Comment: I've bought the complete works of Austen, Dickens, London, Whitman, etc. from Amazon for my Kindle, and none of them have illustrations or annotations.  At least, none that I've noticed.  Perhaps a few were slipped in to meet guidelines?  Or the guidelines change occasionally, and stuff gets grandfathered in?  Or, complete collections from a single author are OK?

Also, to add one more thing to your good answer: Copyright in the U.S. now lasts 150 years (from date of first publication, IIRC).  So, early 19th century poetry is guaranteed to be in the public domain, but not late 18th century.

Comment: There are a couple of different ways in which the examples you gave are currently available through Amazon. First of all, any that were submitted prior to the middle of 2011 were grandfathered in. The current Amazon policy went into effect in Feb. 2011, and started being really enforced about the middle of 2011. The second example are books that were converted from sources such as the Gutenberg Project and are available for free. There are others that may slip through the initial review, but Amazon usually catches those and removes them in time.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where you got the idea that US copyright lasts for 150 years, but that is not correct. The US has had a number of changes to their copyright laws, but basically any books published prior to 1923 are no longer protected. Books published after that had to have their copyright renewed every 28 years or they fell into the public domain. There were a couple of changes that happened between 1964 and 1998 that complicated things further, but the current coverage is for the life of the author plus 70 years.   http://copyright.cornell.edu/resources/publicdomain.cfm

Comment: I was mis-remembering from recent news articles on the Sherlock Holmes copyright case.  Also, I was confusing private & corporate copyright (and then adding 30 years).  Paraphrasing Wikipedia: The Copyright Term Extension Act of 1998 extended copyright terms in the United States to life of the author plus 70 years, and for works of corporate authorship to 120 years after creation or 95 years after publication, whichever endpoint is earlier. For works published before January 1, 1978, the copyright term was increased by 20 years to a total of 95 years from publication.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance to public domain of several points you
raise regarding 19th century publications. Why should it matter that a
poem was published in different anthologies?  Why should it matter
(other than for asking permission) that copyright ownership changed
hands or was retained by the author? Why should a poem not be truly in
the public domain, meaning I guess that it would seem to be according to one
source of information, but would not because of an undiscovered fact ?

Answer (score 0):

IANAL - not a lawyer

It is hard to answer your question, because though it seems very
simple, it is probably not the question you wanted to ask.

Can you create a collection of works. Certainly, even if they are
still under copyright, as long as it is for your own use, and not made
public. If you want to publish that collection, even if only on your
personnal web site, for free, you have to get permission from the
copyright holder or to restrict yourself to works in the public
domain.

You specify that you are interested in "19th century public domain
poems". If it is public domain, you have nothing to worry about
(skipping possibly moral rights in some countries). But then why
specify "19th century", which is an irrelevant information ?  I
suspect, possibly wrongly, that you think that they should be public
domain because they were written in the 19th century. That is a wrong
assumption.

The assumption is probably true if the poems were first published in
the USA; I am not sure, since the history of copyright law in the USA
created a very messy situation. However, even if written in English,
or authored by an american citizen, these works could have been published first
in another country than the USA. Then this other country is considered
as **country of origin** of the work ([Berne Convention art. 5](http://www.wipo.int/treaties/en/ip/berne/trtdocs_wo001.html#P109_16834)). In that case, the
general rules of the Berne convention apply, even for works published
before 1923, and it is essentially the current US copyright law that
has to be taken into account. The duration of copyright is author's
life + 70 years. This means that the early works of an author who died
in 1960 at the age of 90 will not be in the public domain before 2031,
even though they were published in the 19th century. (this is in
agreement with the comment of user dmm, though I do not know where he
got the 150 years figure, which makes no sense to me).

Note, furthermore that when the country of origin is not the USA, the
work need not be registered with the U.S. Copyright Office for its
copyright to be protected in the U.S.A. (unlike works of
U.S. origin). But the protection remains minimal without registration
(see [articles 411](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#411) and [412](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#412) of US Copyright Law).

Hence, to know about the copyright situation, you have to investigate
among other things were the work was initially published.

The fact that copyright ownership may have changed hands, through sale
or heritage, is totally irrelevant, except for the fact that only the
current holder of the copyright may give you permission, and he must
be identified and contacted.

The fact that the poem may have been published in several anthologies
or collections is irrelevant. The country of origin for the copyright results from the first
publication (see country of origin issue above). That means however that you may
have to ascertain where a particular piece was published first, which may not be obvious for a small piece that may have been published several times, as part of different collections.

It is often the case that copyright is transferred to the publisher
when the work is published, but this is not always the case. It is
purely a contractual matter.

Another point is that copyright is not a monolithic entity. It can be
cut in pieces. For example the author may have tranferred copyright
for printed publication to his publisher, while retaining digital
copyright.  This is implicitly the case in some (many?) countries as
the publication contracts before 2000 did not generally include
transfer of digital rights.

So if you intend to publish your collection, the kind of rights you
have to clear, and the rights holders who can grant permission, are
not necessarily the same, depending on how you want to publish. However, the duration of these rights is the
same and depend only on the date of the author's demise.

Note that you do not have to depend on publishers. It is quite possible to publish books without them. Indeed, one may wonder whether there is any reason for their existence in the digital world.

Another point is whether you can claim some rights over your
collection. Essentially, yes, if it can show originality or serious investment (laws vary ... which is a problem for Internet publication), which does
not mean simply being different from other collections - a very
subjective assessment. This gives you no right over individual works
in the collection.

And of course there are even more complicated situations. Copyright is mostly an exercise in futile complexity and obfuscation, at the expense of authors and public.